# Is it possible to select two different part of input string simultaneously using element.select() function of JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, selection

I want to select two different part of input string simultaneously, which looks something like this:

[image]

so far I have achieved this using JavaScript `element.select()` function:

[image]

Here is the code for what I have done so far:

```js
const inp = document.getElementById("inp");
const sel = document.getElementById("sel");

function selectMe() {
  inp.select();
  inp.setSelectionRange(2, 7);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="inp" value="this is sample text for demo" style="width:300px;"><button id="sel" onclick="selectMe()">select</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: No, not with [`.select()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/select), and unfortunately not with [`Selection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection) either: "*the Selection API was initially created by Netscape and allowed multiple ranges (for instance, to allow the user to select a column from a <table>). However, browsers other than Gecko did not implement multiple ranges, and the specification also requires the selection to always have a single range.*"